# json4s and Joda Time

Tags: scala, json4s

I am having difficulties with Joda time and json4s, the error I am getting is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/Manifest$
    at org.json4s.ext.DurationSerializer$.<init>(JodaTimeSerializers.scala:41)
    at org.json4s.ext.DurationSerializer$.<clinit>(JodaTimeSerializers.scala)
    at org.json4s.ext.JodaTimeSerializers$.all(JodaTimeSerializers.scala:26)
    at com.xxx.dts.toolset.jsonWrite$.jsonClob(jsonWrite.scala:21)
    at com.xxx.dts.dq.profiling.DQProfilingEngine.profile(DQProfilingEngine.scala:253)
    at com.xxx.dts.dq.profiling.Profiler$.main(DQProfilingEngine.scala:58)
    at com.xxx.dts.dq.profiling.Profiler.main(DQProfilingEngine.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.reflect.Manifest$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 16 more
```

For json4s I have the following setup:

```
     implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats ++ org.json4s.ext.JodaTimeSerializers.all

val  dateTime = new DateTime()
("Date" -> dateTime.toString)
```

Comment: which scala version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this problem doesn't have much to do with json4s itself. Searching the web for `NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/Manifest$` turns up a lot of reports of errors which seem to have something to do with jar version problems and maybe other configuration problems.

Comment: Hmm strange because once I removed  ++ org.json4s.ext.JodaTimeSerializers.all everything worked again.

Comment: To judge by the results of a web search, JodaTimeSerializers is in a separate jar, json4s-ext.jar. Maybe the version of json4s-ext is conflicting with other json4s jar(s). Just guessing here.